# Does $\int\limits_0^\infty \left(x^2+1\right)^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)^2+1\right)^{-1}...dx=\frac{\pi^2}{20\ln{\phi}}$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, function-and-relation-composition

In other words, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

$$\int\limits_0^\infty\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty(\underbrace{f^{(0)}\circ f^{(1)}\circ...\circ f^{(n-1)}}_{n\text{ times}})(x)dx\stackrel{?}{=}1$$

On desmos, I got the following data:

$$\begin{array}{c|c} 
 t & \int\limits_0^\infty\prod\limits_{n=1}^t(\underbrace{f^{(0)}\circ f^{(1)}\circ...\circ f^{(n-1)}}_{n\text{ times}})(x)dx \\ \hline
 1 & 1.57079632679 \\ \hline
 2 & 1.38188007993 \\ \hline
 3 & 1.21975874971 \\ \hline
 4 & 1.1216186939 \\ \hline
 5 & 1.06594019043 \\ \hline
 6 & 1.0257942799
\end{array}$$

$t=6$ seems to be Desmos's limit.

The reason I suspect $\frac{\pi^2}{20\ln{\phi}}$ is just because I recognised it fairly quickly because I saw the constant a lot messing around with my favorite integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788208/a-cool-integral-int-ln-phi-0-ln-leftex-e-x-rightdx-frac-pi) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828799/ways-to-milk-the-integral-int1-0-ln-left-phix-phi-x-right-ln-l). Other possible closed forms I suspect it might converge to include $1$ and $\sec^2\frac{\pi}{20}$ but I have no clue how I solve this.

What does it converge to?

---

**Edit**

I no longer believe it converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{20\ln{\phi}}$. I think it converges to $1$.

Extended Data Chart:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c} 
 t & b & \int\limits_0^b\prod\limits_{n=1}^t(\underbrace{f^{(0)}\circ f^{(1)}\circ...\circ f^{(n)}}_{n\text{ times}})(x)dx \\ \hline
 7 & 73158 & 0.999768060968 \\ \hline
 8 & 257 & 0.970229056434 \\
\end{array}$$

> $b$ is the largest integer (or $\infty$) upper bound of the integral that Desmos would support.

Everything just breaks after $t=8$ and I don't really trust the data for $t=7$ and $t=8$ because of how small the intervals are. I suspect it converges to $1$.

Comment: Probably the $t=7$ result would not be $\approx 1.025$. Also, the $n$th derivative, by partial fractions, would be $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{x^2+1}=\frac{i n!}2((i-x)^{-n-1}-(-i-x)^{-n-1})$

Comment: @ТymaGaidash I now believe it converges to $1$ as I stated in my edit. Should I edit the title of my post?

Comment: Maybe try to ask on math over flow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/)